# Parsing a timestamp containg the date, time & offset

Tags: java, date, iso8601

I'm using using [Java 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29).

I need to parse date-time strings in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format such as `2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+00:00`:

```
String dateString = "2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+00:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
Date parsed=null;
try {
    parsed = df.parse(dateString);
}
```

I have also tried this pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz`, but get same result:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+00:00"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I corrected the term "timezone" in your title to "offset". A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is an offset from UTC in `hours:minutes` *plus* a set of historical, present, and future rules regarding how to handle anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Comment: For later versions of Java, use the java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes (`SimpleDateFormat` & `Date`). The java.time classes also supplant the Joda-Time project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Joda-Time

You have to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [(Maven)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.6) (supports Java 1.5) if you don't want to parse it manually. Just create an object with `new DateTime(String)` then you can get `Date` via `toDate()` method.

### Time Zone

Pass the time zone you want assigned to the resulting date-time object. Unlike java.util.Date, a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object knows its own assigned time zone ([`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)). If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is assigned implicitly.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Or perhaps DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+00:00", zone );
```

Comment: When a parse this dateTimeFormat:  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); with date: 2015-01-14T00:00:00-04:00 i get: 2015-01-13T23:00:00.000-05:00

Comment: What did you mean with "i get"? You can get this with `toString` if your timezone is  `-05:00`

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the colon from `+00:00`, as this format only works with the `X` pattern, which is not available in [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), only from [Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

More information: RFC822 needs this style (without colon), in ISO 8601 both is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you have currently used in your `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, is supposed to accept timestamps in the following format:

```
2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+0000
```

however, what you need is something that will handle timestamps such as:

```
2011-11-30T12:00:00.000+00:00
```

For this particular purpose, the `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` format should be specified in your `SimpleDateFormat` (*i.e.* the problem lies within the formatting of the timestamp's timezone component).

Comment: @roberttrudel: Yes, sorry, didn't realize that at the time of posting. You're still free to reformat all your timestamps to exclude the colon (`:`) as @meskobalazs pointed out in his well-informed reply.

Comment: Then you should just remove the colon in the time zone.  Use an indexOf(".") to find the position of the period, the use that position to find the time zone colon, dateString.indexOf((":"),dateString.indexOf(".")).  Then use substring operations to remove the colon.